# wifi connection on ubuntu 14.10 is very slowly and inestable after some time of use internet

Tags: networking, wireless, 14.10, broadcom

my wifi connection is very slowly and inestable, i install dual boot on my machine in windows 8.1 wifi is ok, but in ubuntu kernel 3.16 after some minutes is each time more slowly, my card information (`sudo lshw -C network`) is

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 38:b1:db:fd:6b:1b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.0.14 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:16 memory:b2500000-b2507fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: d0:bf:9c:88:76:2f
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:44 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2404000-b2404fff memory:b2400000-b2403fff
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not an update or something else that is starting to run (like normally in Windows...) Check processor activity with System Monitor and test network speed (with a known speed test site) to confirm. Disconnect and reconnect and do speed test again to make sure it is a driver or configuration issue. Sorry, this is all I can help.

Comment: my wireless network speed is ok, I have tested all solutions in this page http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/ but nothing work for me, please you can tell me how to I can debug the wireless connection, or maybe I should try with ubuntu 14.04 or 15.04.

Comment: nobody can answer something? there are to many people with this issue and nobody can give one tip? that sad.

Comment: If the standard log with dmesg or /var/log/messages don't give extra information you need to delve deeper into the other log files. netstat can give you instant monitoring information. Are you connecting to a home network with possible windows authentication issues? - just a shot in the dark.